# Laravel Application Environment - Best practice and security advice

Tags: php, security, laravel, laravel-4

I am planning on building a multi-tenant application in Laravel with a master subdomain holding the relevant public files and a subdomain for each customer who will have their own databases pointing to the 'master' files. I am planning on doing this as automated as possible e.g. you click a button a subdomain is created, a database is created and the relevant config files are set. All this is fine except I'm not sure if my practices are the best to use and whether or not there are any security issues with it.

In the `bootstrap/start.php` file I have the following:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] => array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
));
```

This would essentially mean that the environment for test.example.co.uk is test.example.co.uk. My install script will create a config directory 'test.example.co.uk` in 'app/config' and will add the relevant database config there.

This does all work as I expected so I am just looking for advice, are there any vulnerabilities with this?

Just to Add - Users will not be able to use the installation script, its just for the developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any security issues with your code. One thing that I notice is that you are limiting youself to just one environment. Here is my env settings:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return getenv("ENV") ? : "local";
});
```

Now my environment will be auto detected - on server I did provide "hook"
in the form of **getenv** function, and on local machine it is **local**.
Also instead of array, I am sending callback to **detectEnvironment** - for more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks carousel, my reason for cautiousness was because I had read that the environment detection had been dropped from version 4.1 because of security concerns, but I cant really see how my setup could be vulnerable. Thanks for your input